# 360 Videos - HLS streaming using react native

Tags: react-native, virtual-reality, 360-video

I wanted to understand if there's a way to streaming 360 videos using HLS protocol without using the web view in react-native application.
If none, how do I optimize the web-view.

Comment: Could you solve this somehow?